# Integration with respect to measure over set involving integration variable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, levy-processes

I have been learning some measure theory for my research and encountered the following in a theorem in a paper on Lévy-driven Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes

$$\int_{|z|\geq 1} \log{(1+|z|) \nu(dz)} <\infty$$

where $\nu(z)$ is the Lévy measure of the Lévy process.

Given $\nu(z)$, how can I show this integral is finite?

I know how to solve it if the integration region was $\mathbb{R}$ but I don't know how to deal with the integration region $|z|\geq 1$.

Moreover, I'm interested in the case $\nu(z) = \lambda \delta(z-k)$ (the Lévy measure for a Poisson process with jumps of size $k>0$. Thanks for your help!

*Edit*: I found a paper in which they mention that to prove the integral is finite it is sufficient to prove $\mathbb{E}[\log{(1 \lor |z|)}]$ is finite. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in another paper. The expression

$$\int_{|z|\geq 1} \log{(1+|z|) \nu(dz)} <\infty$$

is equivalent to showing that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \log{(1 \lor |z|) \nu(dz)} <\infty$$ 
$$\mathbb{E}[\log{(1 \lor |z|)}] <\infty$$

Hence, for $\nu(z) = \lambda \delta(z-k)$,
$$\int_{|z|\geq 1} \log{(1+|z|) \nu(dz)} <\infty$$

for $k$ finite since $\mathbb{E}[\log{(1 \lor |z|)}] = \log{(1 \lor |k|)}$.